# What determines an automatic visitor's music?

Tags: miitomo

If someone visits you in Miitomo, the main music will change to some different music. I would like to know if this music is determined by any factors, or if it is chosen randomly. I have currently heard 4 different pieces of visitor music (Vacation, one with only beats, some sort of disco one and some sort of Japanese music).

**What factors determine the music if someone visits you in Miitomo?** I'm not talking about the manual visits, I'm talking about when a friend automatically visits you in your room, where the music changes to another one temporarily.

Answer (score 1):

The BGM change is dependent by the visitor's character.

> 性格の系統によってMiiのリアクションや部屋のデザインが変わる。また、フレンドの部屋を訪れたときのBGMは、そこの住人の性格（系統）によって異なるようだ。

([Source](http://app.famitsu.com/20160325_678545/))